# SOQL - aggregrate checkbox fields

Tags: soql

Need some SOQL help. How can I get back a nice list of counts for each checkbox fields.

Example:

```
Select CheckField1,CheckField2 FROM Account_Counselor WHERE User = '123..'
```

This will currently give me three rows with T/F for each field.

I want 1 row with a count of true values.

Like:

```
User CheckField1   CheckField2
123       1          (blank)
```

Comment: Do want to both the CheckField1,CheckField2 are true for those accounts which will be listed as results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkboxes don't support aggregate functions, try this:

```
integer CheckField1 = 0;
integer CheckField2 = 0;

for (Account_Counselor counselor :[Select CheckField1,CheckField2 FROM Account_Counselor WHERE User = '123..']){
    if (counselor.CheckField1) {
        CheckField1++;
    }
        if (counselor.CheckField2) {
        CheckField2++;
    }
}

system.debug('123..: CheckField1: ' + CheckField1 + ' CheckField2: ' + CheckField2);
```

Or you can create formula field formulaCheck1 (return number):

```
if (CheckField1__c, 1, 0)
```

And aggregate by it:

```
select sum(formulaCheck1__c) from Account_Counselor where User = '123...' group by User
```

Comment: His question is bit different

Comment: If SOQL doesn't support it directly then I'll do something different. Thanks

Comment: @llyaLepesh COUNT will return wrong output

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 formula fields `formulaCheck1__c` and `formulaCheck2__c` like this:

`formulaCheck1__c = if (CheckField1__c, 1, 0)`

`formulaCheck2__c = if (CheckField2__c, 1, 0)`

And perform the SOQL query as follows:

```
SELECT User,SUM(formulaCheck1__c), SUM(formulaCheck2__c) FROM Account_Counselor 
WHERE User = '123..'
GROUP BY User
```

It will give you desired result.

```
User CheckField1   CheckField2
 123       4          3
```

**If you do not want to use formula field** then use this type of query:

```
SELECT Check1__c, Check2__c,GROUPING(Check1__c) grpCheck1, GROUPING(Check2__c) grpCheck2,
COUNT(id) accts
FROM Account_Counselor 
WHERE User = '123..' 
GROUP BY CUBE(Check1__c, Check2__c)
HAVING GROUPING(Check1__c) = 1 OR GROUPING(Check2__c) = 1
ORDER BY COUNT(id), Check1__c, Check2__c 
LIMIT 2
```

It will give the results as shown in picture:

[image]

You can find the check2 field count is 3 and check1 field count is 4 as I have shown earlier.

For more information on how GROUP BY CUBE works, visit this documentation
[GROUP BY CUBE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_cube.htm)